# Samba mount only allows modification if root

Tags: permissions, mount, samba, synology, cifs

I am attempting to mount a Samba share from a Synology.  It's still Samba and Linux.  The Guest OS is Ubuntu 16.04.  When Ubuntu mounts the directory, it looks just dandy.  However, I am unable to make changes to anything in that directory unless I sudo the modification attempt, at which point it works just fine.  I don't understand why.  The user on both devices is `art`, which I'm sure doesn't muddy the waters at all.  `</sarcasm>`

I have the below line in `/etc/fstab`:

```
//192.168.1.14/files/Dropbox    /home/art/Dropbox       cifs    credentials=/home/art/.smbcredentials,uid=1001,gid=1001,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,_netdev 0       0
```

`.smbcredentials` has the user's login information for the Samba share.

```
username=art
password=XXXXXXXXXXX
```

How can I make this so I can modify it without needing root access?

Comment: I would have checked the control panel -> user -> permission settings, Synology uses a modified Linux and your mileage might vary if you treat it just as a Linux.

Answer (score 0):

The file `/home/art/.smbcredentials` was owned by root, readable only by root, but was in an inappropriate directory.  Moving it to `/root` corrected the issue.  Perms on `/home/art` were 755, but that was not enough.

Now that the file is owned by root (no change there) and in `/root`, it functions as desired.